# EF Code First Migration: Controlling the name of code file

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-migrations

As we know, calling the command `Add-Migration <name>` generates a code file to reflect changes in the model. However, the generated file name is `<timestamp>+<name>` which `<timestamp>` comes from the client on which the command is executed, something like: "`20150603123_AddNameProperty.cs`"

**Questions:**

1- Any way to get the timestamp from a server not client?

2- Any way to automatically put a prefix in generated file name, for example: 
"`20150603123_HansModifications_AddNameProperty.cs`"

3- Any way to automatically generate the file name in a sequential manner, for example:
"`20150603123_1.cs`", "`20150603123_2.cs`", "`20150603123_3.cs`",...

Comment: "...from a server..." - which server? The only relevant one would be your VCS. It is a valid question but it is about cosmetics, functionally the name only has to be unique (and ascending). You can probably just rename it manually (I never tried).

Comment: Well, by server I mean another computer, VCS, a domain controller, anything to centralize the timestamp. You admit that renaming is not an option in high pace production.

Comment: Why would you need it ?